# Needle in haystack: How to get value from array of objects via computed property?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to loop through the following JSON:

```
[ { "target": { "source": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vue-photoapp-api.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fmountains-hero.jpg?alt=media&token=fbe93188-d13d-4a7f-a472-4a529aa565a0", "selector": { "conformsTo": "http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/", "value": "xywh=pixel:378.2608642578125,328.9855041503906,147.82611083984375,210.14492797851562", "type": "FragmentSelector" } }, "photoDocId": "92wNwz2aaqy7CWf3mGo1", "body": [ { "value": "new annotation", "purpose": "commenting", "type": "TextualBody" }, { "purpose": "tagging", "type": "TextualBody", "value": "error" } ], "id": "698RTBGMwWahQ15rXbe6", "type": "Annotation", "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld" }, { "photoDocId": "92wNwz2aaqy7CWf3mGo1", "target": { "source": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vue-photoapp-api.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fmountains-hero.jpg?alt=media&token=fbe93188-d13d-4a7f-a472-4a529aa565a0", "selector": { "conformsTo": "http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/", "value": "xywh=pixel:695.6521606445312,60.869564056396484,139.13043212890625,127.53622817993164", "type": "FragmentSelector" } }, "id": "AUMwWBjizjl8L8vU0XtA", "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld", "type": "Annotation", "body": [ { "value": "clouds!", "type": "TextualBody", "purpose": "commenting" }, { "type": "TextualBody", "value": "clouds", "purpose": "tagging" } ] }, { "type": "Annotation", "body": [ { "type": "TextualBody", "value": "fourth anno", "purpose": "commenting" } ], "target": { "source": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vue-photoapp-api.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fmountains-hero.jpg?alt=media&token=fbe93188-d13d-4a7f-a472-4a529aa565a0", "selector": { "type": "FragmentSelector", "conformsTo": "http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/", "value": "xywh=pixel:631.884033203125,389.8551025390625,172.4637451171875,128.9854736328125" } }, "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld", "id": "CecyGAt47krNIOPgk8Su", "photoDocId": "92wNwz2aaqy7CWf3mGo1" }, { "photoDocId": "92wNwz2aaqy7CWf3mGo1", "body": [ { "type": "TextualBody", "purpose": "commenting", "value": "mountain top . Anyone ever climbed this?" }, { "value": "mountain", "type": "TextualBody", "purpose": "tagging" } ], "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld", "id": "KxIMdih1fTSULjde3Ay4", "type": "Annotation", "target": { "selector": { "type": "FragmentSelector", "value": "xywh=pixel:272.4637756347656,60.869564056396484,252.17391967773438,185.50725173950195", "conformsTo": "http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/" }, "source": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vue-photoapp-api.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fmountains-hero.jpg?alt=media&token=fbe93188-d13d-4a7f-a472-4a529aa565a0" } } ]
```

I want to return just the following values:

`purpose`, `type`, and `value`. They are located within the `body` array of `clientAnnos`

Will this need to be a v-for within a v-for loop?

Update: I tried:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="{ body, index } in clientAnnos" :key="index">
    {{ body }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I am wondering if there's possible update issues due to index variable not having a true id.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by mapping through the data then looping through the body since its an array. You can use a method for this for example

```
methods: {
  info() {
    let required = this.data.map(d => d.body)
    return required
  }
 }
```

Then use the blog as a data value in the v for. The method will return an array of the body array properties

```
<li v-for="{ body, index } in info" :key="index">
   {{ body }}
</li>
```

I hope it helps...